# Unable to login to TP-Link web-interface

Tags: login, modem

I just bought a TP-Link Archer VR1210v and I now wanted to access the admin-panel. I managed to open the page, but it only shows one input field and the "Log In" button doesn't do anything.
What should I do?

[The admin-panel-login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op6OZ.png)

Edit: Even a hardware-reset or using a different browser didn't solve the problem

Solution:
My browsers language was german, but the admin-panel could not load that language and it seems to have no fallback (or equivalent), so the site just broke. I changed my language to english and now it works.

Comment: Have you tried inputting the default password? I believe it's `admin`.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes i did, but nothing happened. The button-element seems to have no event attached

Comment: Chrome? IE? Edge? Firefox? Try a different browser.

Comment: I did, didn't change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: My browsers language was german, but the admin-panel could not load that language and it seems to have no fallback (or equivalent), so the site just broke. I changed my language to english and now it works.